# Using gml:FeatureCollection / gml:featureMember in GMLAS driver via ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, gml

Does anyone know how to force the use of the gml:FeatureCollection and gml:featureMember prefixes instead wfs:FeatureCollection and wfs:member, when exporting gml via ogr2ogr using GMLAS driver.Modifying the files gmlasconf.xml and gmlasconf.xsd had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but first you'll need to make sure your output format is GML3.2 (which is when that change was made I think).

If that is not enough then there is a mention in the [docs](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gmlas.html) of `WRAPPING=GMLAS_FEATURECOLLECTION` as a dataset creation option which says it will export as a `ogr_gmlas:FeatureCollection` which might be what you need.

Comment: I tested WRAPPING=GMLAS_FEATURECOLLECTION, but still not getting the desired effect. I read that gml:FeatureCollection has been deprecated in GML 3.2. I thought it would be possible to force GMLAS to use GML (FeatureCollection) instead of GML (WFS 2.0 FeatureCollection), but I guess I'll have to manually process the xml files.

Comment: can you add your actual command line to the question